# Change home directory for opening projects in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I've been searching around and confused with the results here as the others here in stackoverflow are saying its not possible or is via the vmoptions file. But all I wanted was just simply change the projects home directory showing when I'm opening my projects as I have to navigate too many folders just to get to my directory where all my projects are. Hence I'm posting this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do so, after opening IntelliJ with any existing project,

- Go to File > Settings / Ctrl + Alt + S

[image]

- On the left pane, navigate to Appearance & Behavior . System Settings
  [image]
- Find the Project Opening section, and then click the folder icon to find the directory to set  the new home directory for opening projects.
- Click Apply

Then you'd now be able to automatically navigate to this directory whenever trying to open your projects folder.